# R Web scraping coinmarketcap with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to get a table from coinmarketcap.com using the `rvest`-package.

A solution approach is shown below. However, this one does not work anymore. The resulting table is empty.
Apparently, the website has been changed somehow.

Can anyone provide a solution?

Many thanks in advance!

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)

url<- "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/"

table <- url %>% 
  read_html()%>%
  html_table() %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to overhead of a browser. You can mimic the API call and parse the json response.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

data <-jsonlite::read_json('https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/ohlcv/historical?id=1&convert=USD&time_start=1614297600&time_end=1619395200')$data$quotes
df <- map_df(data, function(x) {data.frame(x$quote)})
print(df)

# 1614297600 is Fri Feb 26 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0000     for 2021-02-27
# 1619395200  Mon Apr 26 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0000       for  2021-04-25
```

The `time_start` and `end_start` are unix timestamp with what looks like a day offset though you will need to explore how this works and whether offsets vary across bank holidays/weekends.

Answer (score 1):

The webpage loads dynamically now. You thus need to use `RSelenium` and not just `rvest`.

This code works for me:

```
url<- "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/"

# RSelenium with Firefox
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4546L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(4)

# get the page source
web <- remDr$getPageSource()
web <- xml2::read_html(web[[1]])

table <- html_table(web) %>%
  as.data.frame()

# close RSelenium
remDr$close()
gc()
rD$server$stop()
system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)
```

Comment: Is there also a way to download past periods?
I can only download the period that is currently displayed.
However, on the website I can click on "Load more" at the bottom and I also see older periods.

Comment: @TobKel, yes, it should be possible with `remDr$findElement` and `clickElement()`; perhaps you will find some resources to do that if you google around. If you don't find a solution, you should probably open a new question for that.